# How to I get UTC from NSDateFormatter?

Tags: ios, nsdateformatter

The following code in iOS

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[formatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterFullStyle];
[formatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterLongStyle];
[formatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation: @"UTC"]];
NSString *dateString = [formatter stringFromDate: date];
```

returns a date string like

```
Monday, May 6, 2013, 10:42:10 PM GMT
```

Unfortunately, UTC is not exactly the same at GMT--it's off by one hour when the UK is on daylight savings time. How to I convince NSDateFormatter to actually return UTC rather than GMT?

Comment: When UK is on daylight savings time it's called BST (British Summer Time), not GMT. GMT and UTC are essentially identical. So if the time you're getting back is wrong, I don't think it's because that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14947213/nstimezone-any-difference-between-utc-and-gmt), the two are implemented the same in code. I don't believe you need to worry about it.